# How can I resize the image for all iOS devices?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, imageview

I have an UITableViewCell and inside that I have a UIImageView. In this class I load a image from the server but the problem is that that image looks very elongated in some devices. How can I achieve to the image size looks equals in all devices?

This is my UITableViewCell and my UIImageView configuration.
[image: TableView]

[image: ImageView]

And this is the code that I'm using to set the image from model to the ImageView:

```
func setElementsWithModel(model : XSModelMarca?, position: Int) -> Void {
    self.index = position
    var frameworkBundle:Bundle? {
        let bundleId = "com.exagono.dcnetfw.DCNetFW"
        return Bundle(identifier: bundleId)
    }
    if model != nil {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            self.mImgBackground.image = UIImage(named: XSUtils.getBackgroudWithClave(marca: model!.mMarca), in: frameworkBundle, with: .none)
        } else {
            self.mImgBackground.image = UIImage(named: XSUtils.getBackgroudWithClave(marca: model!.mMarca), in: frameworkBundle, compatibleWith: nil)
        }
        self.priceButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: XSUtils.getColorWithMarca(marca: model!.mMarca))
        self.modelButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: XSUtils.getColorWithMarca(marca: model!.mMarca))
    }
}
```

And this is the example how looks in different Simulator Devices:

[image: iPhone 13 Mini]

[image: iPhone 13 Pro Max]

[image: iPod touch 7th]

[image: iPhone 8]

Any suggestions for resolve this problem (?)

Thank you.

Comment: Set s constraint so that the image height is always the same % of the width, and let your cells resize to accommodate the variable image height.

Comment: @flanker How can I achieve this (?) Can you tell me any example (?) Please.

Comment: The answer below may help you...

Comment: what layout do you want in all devices ?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I did constraints in IB, but you need to set the width constraint to a multiple of the height constraint.  This will keep the image ratio at a constant ratio.

If you a 6:9 image you'd set it 0.66.  In code it would look something like this

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
         myview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myview.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.66)
])
```

You can do the same in IB.

You could even expose the width and height constraints into your viewController through IBOutlets and use the above.  BUT mixing IB and code constraints is not a good idea generally as it makes it hard to work out what's happening when you look at it in the future.